# Adding automatic image numbers in React: how to determine the number of elements prior to a React element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm writing an online educational book through React. I want to add images with automatic image numbers. So I have some JSX code like:

```
<Page>
<p>Some text.</p>
<Img src={cat} caption={This is a cat} />
<p>Some more text.</p>
<Img src={dog} caption={This is a dog} />
</Page>
```

The `<Img />` object is one I've made myself that formats the image and puts the caption underneath. However, I want to add a figure number to this caption: "Figure 1: This is a cat" and "Figure 2: This is a dog". This numbering should be done automatically, so that if I add an extra figure at the start, the numbers will shift. The big question is: how?

I've tried to add a Context to `<Page />` with a counter accessed by the `<Img />` components. However, the order in which the images render is not set in stone, resulting in random image numbers. So in some way the `<Img />` component needs to figure out what number image it is on the page: how many images precede it. Is this possible? The alternative is to pass along image numbers manually through `<Img src={cat} number={counter++} />` but this is a hassle and prone to errors.

I appreciate any suggestions that may solve this.

Comment: Are you getting the images from an array?

Comment: This is a pretty interesting question

Comment: One hackey way to do it would be to just use Dom traversal to do it. If you gave them all the same class, and used a `querySelectorAll`, the order that the elements come back in from that would be the actual order they appear in the DOM

Comment: I like TKoL's idea. So the steps are then as follows:
(1) Within the Page object use a Ref object (through ```useRef```) that will track images on that page.
(2) Within the Img object use an effect that "registers" itself at the Page object, effectively storing itself in above Ref.
(3) Whenever a new image is rendered, the image asks the page to check the order of images through the ```querySelectorAll```. The page then uses registered callbacks to inform each image of its number.
(4) The image stores the received number in a state.
It's a bit of a hassle, but should be possible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to TKoL's `querySelectorAll` idea I have found a (slightly roundabout) solution. The code below makes it work.

```
function ChapterOnAnimals() {
    return (
        <Chapter>
            <p>This chapter shows various animals.</p>
            <p>In image <ImageNumber id="cat" /> you see a cat.</p>
            <Image src={cat} id="cat" caption="This is a cat." />
            <p>Next, in image <ImageNumber id="dog" />, you see a dog.</p>
            <Image src={dog} id="dog" caption="This is a dog." />
            <p>This is the end of the chapter.</p>
        </Chapter>
    )
}

const ChapterContext = createContext({})

function Chapter({ children }) {
    const chapterRef = useRef(null)
    const imageTracker = useRef({})

    const updateImageNumbers = () => {
        const imageTags = [...chapterRef.current.querySelectorAll('.image')]
        Object.values(imageTracker.current).forEach(imageData => {
            const imageIndex = imageTags.indexOf(imageData.ref.current)
            if (imageIndex === -1)
                delete imageData.number
            else
                imageData.number = imageIndex + 1 // Count from 1.
        })
    }
    const registerImage = (id, ref) => {
        imageTracker.current[id] = { ref }
        updateImageNumbers()
    }
    const unregisterImage = (id) => {
        delete imageTracker.current[id]
        updateImageNumbers()
    }

    const data = {
        registerImage,
        unregisterImage,
        imageData: imageTracker.current,
    }

    return (
        <ChapterContext.Provider value={data}>
            <div className="chapter" ref={chapterRef}>
                {children}
            </div>
        </ChapterContext.Provider>
    )
}

function Image({ src, id, caption }) {
    const imageRef = useRef(null)
    useImageTracking(id, imageRef)
    const num = useImageNumber(id)

    return <div className="image" ref={imageRef}>
        <img src={src} alt="id" />
        <div className="caption">Figure {num}: {caption}</div>
    </div>
}

function ImageNumber({ id }) {
    return <span className="imageNumber">{useImageNumber(id)}</span>
}

function useImageTracking(id, imageRef) {
    const { registerImage, unregisterImage } = useContext(ChapterContext)
    useEffect(() => {
        registerImage(id, imageRef)
        return () => unregisterImage(id)
    }, [id, imageRef])
}

function useImageNumber(id) {
    const { imageData } = useContext(ChapterContext)
    return (imageData && imageData[id] && imageData[id].number) || '?'
}
```

Some notes on this:

- Naturally this code should be split up over various files, adding imports, layout and everything.
- I have not tested dynamic adding of images. Statically the above works, which is my default use case.
- I have not tested for efficiency. Maybe some objects rerender a bit too often now.
- I have not tested the above if there are multiple chapters on one page. I think it still works, but I'm not 100% sure.
- Once chapter numbers come into play, like "Figure 2.3" in chapter 2, then I should extend the above. I think it's manageable using the same `ChapterContext` though, so this should not require extra components.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `` <Img src={dog} caption={`Figure ${++counter} : This is a cat`} /> `` which will give the value after increment of counter. So if counter is initialized to 0, result will be Figure 1, then Figure 2, etc...

Comment: This solution is less preferably than the work-around suggested in the question. If, at some later point, the name 'Figure' should be changed to 'Image' or something similar, then it should be done at dozens of places instead of one. So this is a no-go.